# TSLint detecting parse error in type guard but TS compiler not detecting any errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tslint

I have the following TypeScript method with a type guard:

```
export function isArray(item: any): item is Array<any> {
    return item.constructor === Array;
}
```

When I run `tslint` on the file, I get the following output:

```
1:42  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

> 1 | export function isArray(item: any): item is Array<any> {
    |                                          ^
  2 |     return item.constructor === Array
  3 | }
```

The type guard is throwing some sort of syntactic parse error in my linter. This is just one example, it's happened in every type guard I've written.

**Any thoughts on what could be causing this issue?** I couldn't seem to find anyone else with it online.

---

**Appendix**

My typescript/tslint versions are:

```
"tslib": "1.9.3",
"tslint": "5.13.1",
"tslint-config-prettier": "1.18.0",
"tslint-eslint-rules": "5.4.0",
"tslint-react": "3.6.0",
"typescript": "3.3.3333",
```

My `tslint` config is:

```
{
    "extends": [
        "tslint:latest",
        "tslint-react",
        "tslint-eslint-rules",
        "tslint-config-prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-submodule-imports": [true, "react-native-vector-icons"],
        "interface-name": [true, "always-prefix"],
        "object-literal-sort-keys": [false],
        "semicolon": [true, "never"],
        "jsdoc-format": [false],
        "valid-jsdoc": [false],
        "no-unnecessary-type-assertion": [true],
        "max-classes-per-file": [false, 2],
    },
    "linterOptions": {
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules",
            "app/**/**.js",
            "packager/**"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to run thins code and only linter error was `ERROR: main.ts:1:45 - Array type using 'Array<T>' is forbidden for simple types. Use 'T[]' instead.
ERROR: main.ts:2:38 - Unnecessary semicolon`. Are you sure that versions are the same as in questions?

Answer (score 0):

How are you running TSLint? It could be that your project's TSLint and TypeScript are different than you're running with manually.

If you're running TSLint on the command line, such as with `tslint -c tslint.json`, try updating it and the relevant libraries to their latest:

```
npm i -g tslint@latest typescript@latest tsutils@latest
```

If through an editor/IDE extension, make sure it and the extension are up-to-date.